# Bitbucket pipeline failing for chmod commands in dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've been facing an issue lately with running bitbucket pipeline for my kafka-connect repository that has debezium in it. Its been like 2 years since we have been using this repository and I checked with all teams and noone has touched it.

I get pipeline errors in bitbucket stating

```
/bin/sh -c chmod -R a+r /opt/kafka/plugins /opt/kafka/libs/ && chmod -R a+rx /opt/kafka/plugins/kafka-connect-rabbitmq-source* /opt/kafka/plugins/camel /opt/kafka/plugins/camel/* /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
```

because of this its giving operation not permitted to the folders to which the chmod command is applied for eg:

```
 0.319 chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/kafka/plugins/debezium/debezium-connector-sqlserver': Operation not permitted
```

The error stack is

```
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly help as I'm not able to get my head around this behaviour. as nothing major seems to be changed in the code.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Sunil